# Programmatically create and trust an SSL certificate with C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, webserver

I'm trying to create a small C# web server that works with HTTPS. I've decided to use [this WebServer library](http://webserver.codeplex.com/) since it seems to do everything I'm looking for. I'm not the most knowledgeable person when it comes to SSL/TLS, so I was wondering if anyone could help me get the HTTPS part of it working. Basically, I need it to create an SSL certificate that will work with the web server library ([from this example](http://webserver.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HttpListener&referringTitle=Examples), it looks like it uses an X.509 certificate) and then add that certificate to the trusted certificates for the computer and/or current user.

Here's the code I have so far (basically just copy & pasted from the example):

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Certs\\certificate.dat", "password");

// We do the cast since we want to specify UseClientCert
var listener = HttpListener.Create(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8080, certificate);
listener.RequestReceived+=listener_RequestReceived;
listener.Start(5);
```

Somewhere before that code, I need to check if "C:\Certs\certificate.dat" exists & is trusted by the computer, and if not it should create the certificate and trust it.

The application runs elevated, so permission issues shouldn't be a problem

EDIT 1:
It looks like I should explain what exactly I'm trying to do. I'm attempting to create a program which, when ran, will start the HTTPS web server to be used on the local machine. I'm not trying to use the key to do any sort of real validation, just to let the computer access the HTTPS local page without getting a ton of "OMG THIS PAGE DOESNT HAVE A GOOD SECURITY KEY!!!" errors. It's only meant to be used with test & non-sensitive data, so the actual security doesn't really matter that much, just so long as it works.

On the code side, I'm using [this WebServer library](http://webserver.codeplex.com/) to handle the actual web serving, and the code is from [from this example](http://webserver.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HttpListener&referringTitle=Examples)

Comment: The code is as mysterious as the question.  Afaict, you got the whole certificate process backwards.  Certificates are issued by an authority, not you.  That authority has servers that lets somebody verify that your certificate is legitimate and that you really are who you say you are.  You can't be your own authority, that would be equivalent to my teenage son saying "trust me dad!".  Or you saying that your last name is really "Thepc".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority

Comment: @HansPassant OP may only wants to create a webserver with https support, not to prove he is really what he says he is.

Comment: @HansPassant - you're right, my last name isn't Thepc ;D the idea is that this would be used to set up sort of a "quick test" scenario on a computer where a website could be tested (https and all) with the click of a button. I'm *not* using this as any kind of permanent certificate system. Sorry if the code is too ambiguous; I'll edit the post in a little bit to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create certificate in C# code, you can just bring your own with the program (i.e made by [makecert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bfsktky3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)). To check if it is already installed itearate corresponding `X509Store` to see if it is already installed, if not - add one. Sample can be found at [StoreName enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx) topic.

Here are random lines that you will need to manipulate the stores/certificates from sample on MSDN:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2("c:\\mycerts\\*****.cer");
store.Add(certificate1);
foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection)
{
  Console.WriteLine("certificate name: {0}", x509.Subject);
}
```

Notes:

- adding certificates is privileged operation and may require administrator privilegies for some 
  stores.
- you can look at Fiddler's behavior for certificates and see if you want to have similar prompts. (When enabling HTTPS decryption Fiddler installs own certificates).